# Web image path to local path value converter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I want to load images from web, but cache them and then display to the user from the local storage folder.

I have the following IValueConverter class:

```
public class ImageToIsolatedPathConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var fileName = (string)value;

        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            LoadImage(fileName);
        }

        try
        {
            var file = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            // TODO code to retrieve file and return it
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return fileName;
    }
}
```

The `LoadImage(..)` is as below:

```
private void LoadImage(string imagePath)
{
    var imageFileName = Path.GetFileName(imagePath);
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += async (s1, e1) =>
    {
        if (e1.Error == null)
        {
            try
            {
                bool isSpaceAvailable = IsSpaceIsAvailable(e1.Result.Length);

                if (isSpaceAvailable)
                {
                    // TODO save file using ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

                    using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(imageFileName,
                                        FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                        IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
                    {
                        long fileLen = e1.Result.Length;
                        byte[] b = new byte[fileLen];
                        e1.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                        isfs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                        isfs.Flush();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // not enough space
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Error.Message);
        }
    };

    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(imagePath));
}
```

How do I save the file using `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` from the `WebClient` and then read it from the the same `StorageFolder`?

I need to do this for both windows phone 8 and windows 8 application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't check to see if the Image exist on disk before you try to attempt to download it to LocalStorage?  You're doing it backwards, plus you never wait until the file is downloaded at all (async) so the event will probably fire after the Convert function exits.

Comment: Yes I will do the check before downloading it again later, and you are right about the `async` thing, but this method is derived from `IValueConverter` and it does not allow return type as `Task<object>`, because its defined as `object`, what would you propose?